# Как задать длину <div> в четверть размера окна браузера?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Как задать длину `<div>` ровно в четверть длины окна браузера?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте единицу измерения [`vw`](https://html5book.ru/edinicy-izmereniya-vh-vw-vmin-vmax/)

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `width: 25%` в стили `div`-а.

```html
<div style='width:25%; background-color:red;'>Lorem ipsum </div>
```

Comment: % отмеряется относительно родителя, т.е. данное решение сработает если родителем `div`'а будет `body`, или другой `div` равный размерам экрана (или `body`).